# Cross borwser how to check for html editor changes when attributes order changes relativly?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, tinymce, tinymce-4

My company uses [tinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/) editor for content editing feature.

> **problem :** when saving content (as a bulk HTML string) from browser say (chrome) then view on Firefox
> Attributes order changes as you see in this => [differences in HTML between chrome & Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6wb1.png)

Our problem is based on content.
If content changes, business changes as well.
But in this case user doesn't change content, the browser does.

> **Scenario**
>
> - tinymce is loaded inside a popup
>
> - user edites content & closes the editor popup
>
> - we render edited HTML in a div element (part of a form)
>
> - part of server-side form validation is checking for content (HTML) changes
>
> - using C# to compare saved vs edited HTML content as two strings

Do you have any ideas on how to find the actual changes or could you provide us with a hint about the way to solve this ?

Comment: Would `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'text'});` assist with your desired needs? This will grab the content as text instead of HTML.

Comment: It's required to include HTML when validating content changes @DallasClark

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this occurs is due to how the HTML content is parsed by the browser. At this point of time, TinyMCE cannot guarantee the order of the attributes.

To resolve the issue for your use case, I would suggest parsing the HTML on the server (preferable) or client side before storing the data.

Depending on the technology stack you're on, there are a range of HTML Parsers written in languages from PHP, Java to Ruby. [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) is one of the "go to" parsers these days - unfortunately there are no ASP.NET solutions options as far as I can see.